# How to find an element in an object within an array with 2 conditions using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to use mongoose to find a document based on a query that finds two property values within an object which is in an array. I used the code shown below but it didn't work as expected - it returned documents that contained "kiosk" in the name and also any equipment item in the array that had a count of 3. I want it to only return documents with an equipment name of kiosk and only if it has 3 kiosks. Can anyone assist?

```
  if (equipment && equipment !== "All") {
    const projects = await Project.find({
      $and: [
        {
          "equipment.name": "kiosk",
          "equipment.count": 3,
        },
      ],
    });
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ projects });
    
    return;
  }
```

All I've tried so far is what I've shown. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: _"but it didn't work as expected - it returned documents that contained "kiosk" in the name and also any equipment item in the array that had a count of 3."_ Provide sample documents which did or did not match correctly, and which _shouldn't_ match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use **$elemMatch** operator in mongoose. This used to query array elements that match multiple record.

`const projects = await Project.find({ equipment: { $elemMatch: { name: "kiosk", count: 3, }, }, });`

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is close, but the use of `$and` is not necessary in this case since you're specifying multiple conditions for the same field. You can directly use an object with multiple properties inside the `find` method.

```
if (equipment && equipment !== "All") {
  const projects = await Project.find({
    "equipment.name": "kiosk",
    "equipment.count": 3,
  });
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ projects });
  return;
}
```

**Update**:

If you want to ensure that only the equipment item with the name "kiosk" has a count of 3, you can use the `$elemMatch` operator to specify conditions on elements within an array.

```
if (equipment && equipment !== "All") {
  const projects = await Project.find({
    equipment: {
      $elemMatch: {
        name: "kiosk",
        count: 3,
      },
    },
  });
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ projects });
  return;
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I initially tried and I got the same result. It returned only docs that contained an equipment item name of "kiosk" but so long as one of the other equipment items had a count of 3 then it returned a document.

Comment: If you want to ensure that only the equipment item with the name "kiosk" has a count of 3, you can use the $elemMatch operator to specify conditions on elements within an array. See my updated answer.